# What is the meaning of $\oplus$ and $\otimes$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, notation

I am struggling to fully understand some notation in a book where they use a "crosshair" symbol - first like $\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^n{} Z_j $ where the $Z_j$ are matrices and second like $I_n \otimes \Phi$ where $I_n$ and $\Phi$ are both matrices.

The book is about multivariate statistics and the section is about random coefficient models. There isn't a notation/terminology appendix to refer to. I was going to post a digital pic of the page so that users can see the context (this is at the start of the section).

So is this on topic here or should I post on math.se ?

---

Update: I originally posted this on meta.se and it was migrated here. I am now attaching the photo from the relevant page of the book.
[image]

Comment: $\oplus$, [Direct sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixDirectSum.html); $\otimes$, [Tensor product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerProduct.html).

Comment: @whuber thanks ! That's exactly what I needed. Did you want to make it into an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: I'm too busy now, Joe--a real answer would explain what these things are, rather than resorting to links.  If anyone would care to provide the details in an answer I'd be happy to vote it up, but in the meantime I am glad you can move on with your reading.

Comment: @whuber OK I will upload the digital picture I mentioned to give more context

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In statistics, $$A\oplus B:=\left[\begin{array}{cc}A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{array} \right]$$ and (e.g. for a $2\times 2$-matrix $A$)
$$A\otimes B:=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a_{11}B & a_{12}B \\ a_{21}B & a_{22}B \end{array} \right].$$

This focuses on matrices for their use in statistics as design or hypothesis  matrices etc., where these notations simplify the frequent block structure of such matrices. One can find the name **Kronecker sum** for $\oplus$ and **Kronecker product** for $\otimes$, especially in the manuals of statistical software. (Also very handy is the component wise matrix multiplication $A\#B=[a_{ij}b_{ij}]_{i,j}$ for equally shaped matrices. It's sometimes called Hadamard product.)

In mathematics, $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ have their slightly different typical meaning as direct sum or tensor product of vector spaces or even more general algebraic structures.

Comment: The statistical meaning is identical to the mathematical meaning of direct sum and tensor product of *linear transformations*: these formulas result from writing out the transformations as matrices in a particular basis.

Comment: The theorem holds that the set of $n\times m$-matrices is isomorphic to the set of linear transformations from a $m$ dimensional to a $n$ dimensional vector space. So in the vector space world you are right. But a direct sum exists also between structures like groups. In statistics, the latter is usually not meant.

Comment: @whuber when I first searched for this I came upon [this] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207635/help-identifying-math-symbols-big-crosshair-and-caret) which confused me quite a bit and prompted me to ask the question on CV. Is that link actually showing the same usage, because the accepted anser there says it is "non carrying addition" ?

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch I just wanted to alert you to the comment I just made above toe whuber - also, if you could update your answer to reflect what the meanings are **called** in statistics I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: I never came across this particular meaning of $\oplus$ and I'm not even sure if the accepted answer there is right. But I'm quite sure it is not the Kronecker sum from matrix arithmetic.

Comment: We should be glad that mathematical ideas are far richer than our ability to make orthographic distinctions. Few mathematical symbols--and *none* of the simple one-character ones--have universal meanings. You have to understand them in context. Although $\oplus$ is universally understood as direct sum in a linear algebraic context, computer scientists use it to distinguish addition of bit strings-cum-vectors over $\mathbb F_2$ from addition of bit strings that stand for integers (i.e., without and with carries). The $\wedge$ ("wedge", not "caret"!) similarly has many meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}$

Then,

A$\otimes$B=$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ $\otimes$ $\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}$=\begin{pmatrix} a {\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}}&b{\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}}\\c{\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}}&d{\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}}\end{pmatrix}

And

A$\oplus B=\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: How does this answer differs from the accepted answer?

Comment: I have just answered this question to make it more clear and understandable.. It's my first answer on this platform

Comment: Oh cool, welcome to the site! I just asked because I don't see the added value: your answer is basically the same answer to what was there before

Comment: Thanks, I will try to add more value to this if I found something important